Ubuntu 24.10 does not put sleep monitors to sleep, only blanks them
After upgrading to 24.10 the displays are always on. They go black , when they are supposed to sleep.
Nvidia GPU.
Edit: I discovered that they do go to sleep, but one second after saying "signal lost" they get signal again, and display black-


Did you have a question?

yes, "how to make them actually go to sleep, like before."
